# Can I use cuDNN with OpenCL

Tags: opencl, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, cudnn

I'm trying to install caffe and I wonder if I can use cuDNN with AMD/OpenCL.
Because my graphic card is AMD

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/opencl

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this won't work: [cudnn](/questions/tagged/cudnn) is an extension of [cuda](/questions/tagged/cuda), which is a propriety of [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). Thus, a non-NVIDIA GPU does not support CUDA and thus does not support cuDNN.
With a non NVIDIA card, you cannot run CUDA code (main caffe branch), but you should be able to enjoy opencl GPU code. You should give the [opencl branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/opencl) a chance.

Comment: Okay) Thanks!! I'm going to try

Answer (score 2):

*The short answer* is that if your graphics card is AMD then you'll have to use OpenCL, not cuDNN.  You cannot make them work together.

cuDNN and OpenCL are [competition](https://community.amd.com/thread/170336), and so it doesn't even make sense to try and use them together.

If instead you are asking if you can use NVIDIA's cuDNN library on AMD hardware, the answer is no.  It just isn't compatible.  cuDNN was made specifically to work on the NVIDIA hardware and take advantage of the unique properties of that chip set.

Comment: Okay) I get it. Thanks

Comment: OpenCL is an API/language. It is not a library. It is loosely comparable to CUDA not cuDNN.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenCL variant of cuDNN from Intel:

https://github.com/01org/clDNN/

Since it is OpenCL-based, should work also on AMD GPUs (although I haven't tested it myself)

Comment: I think clDNN relies on some extensions not found in non-Intel Graphics. I see that the kernels are using subgroups (e.g. `intel_sub_group_block_read2`).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid if you can really use it for AMD graphics card since clDNN is built for DL inference in particular for Intel graphics cards (HD and Iris). Check e.g., [OpenVINO toolkit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit) (designed by Intel), it uses clDNN under the hood for [GPU plugins](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_IE_DG_supported_plugins_CL_DNN.html) to accelerate inference on the Intel GPUs.

From the GPU plugin page, it says:

> clDNN is an open source performance library for Deep Learning (DL) applications intended for acceleration of Deep Learning Inference on Intel® Processor Graphics including Intel® HD Graphics and Intel® Iris® Graphics.